# QGIS spatial sort - coalesce?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, spatial-sort

In QGIS (v3.2) is there a spatial sort similar to ArcGIS (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/how-sort-works.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_9C199CD3D68A41029943D4FF79500A73) where you can sort the spatial attribute as LL, UR etc

The reason for this is that I am creating points and start/end points of roads and if there are segments of the road that aren't in the order of the flow of the road sometimes the xat(0) etc get placed in the middle of the road.

I see a solution from last year in [Sort line features into route order in the attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256203/sort-line-features-into-route-order-in-the-attribute-table) and rather than coding this I am wondering if there is a tool now that can be used in modeler. See my other question on this [Sort a table by multiple columns in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194897/sort-a-table-by-multiple-columns-in-qgis) where the last answer introduces coalesce

Comment: have you tried the sort and number plugin as described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/256837/81764

Comment: I have tried this and it still creates a multipart dataset. In ArcGIS there is an option to not allow multipart and this then makes sure the segments that can be joined sequentially are and those that can't are kept seperate. I can then do a count for repeats and whenever the road name exists more than once I can try to trace the issue and fix it.